# RegEx throws Error : Template variables could not be initialized

Tags: python, regex, go, regex-lookarounds

I am using the below regex : `^(?!.*(ab1-canary|cd1-staging|cf-ab1-canary)).*$` ; This works well in python but fails to do so in GO language. Could you please help me in getting the right regex for GO.

Regards,
Rohith

Comment: How does it fail?

Comment: you need to give us some examples and your code as you can.